# Heat generation mathematical model for Li-ion battery to design a BTMS

Tags: battery, electric-vehicles

I have decided to work on a project in which I have to design a hybrid battery thermal management system (BTMS) for which I need to first model the heat generation from Li-ion batteries. Therefore I have been looking for heat generation mathematical models from various technical journals. There are many models out there and as a beginner I don't know which model to use. It would be helpful if I get some suggestions for a best fit heat generation model for a cylindrical Li-ion battery.

Comment: I would start by assuming the ESR generates heat. Model that and compare to an actual battery, then go from there.

Comment: I would do this empirically using the actual battery & charging system you are planning to use.  I wouldn't even trust the battery manufacturer.